# Couldn't ping host ip after bridging on vmware

Tags: networking, vmware, ping

I am using vmware for my vm platform. I want to connect my vm(guest) to my host so i used `Bridge` connection. I got ip for my host's IP `192.168.43.119` (DHCP). I got host's ip from my dhcp wireless ip. and my guest's ip  is `192.168.43.173`. The host's ip is connected to the internet. My guest's ip ( VM ) could ping to `8.8.8.8` but when i am trying ping `192.168.43.119` it gives me nothing. I tried ping my guest's ip (`192.168.43.173`) through my host's ip (`192.168.43.119`) and it works just fine, i tried ping `8.8.8.8` through the same ip and it give the same result . What's wrong with my configuration ?
I tried to ping the Gateway, which came from my host's ip (`192.168.43.1`), and it works too.

The problem is i couldn't ping from guest to host, but i could ping from host to guest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when i am trying ping 192.168.43.119 it gives me nothing. I tried ping my guest's ip (192.168.43.173) through my host's ip (192.168.43.119) and it works just fine

You can ping the guest from the host. You can't ping the host from the guest. This establishes proof of proper connectivity.

The answer is simple - disable the firewall on your host.

Comment: i have disabled it but it didn't work

Comment: nevermind, i have to disabled it too in both the widows firewall main menu advanced setting thanks anyway